# How to drop image under the text within TextView

Tags: android, textview, watermark

How can i drop an image under a piece of text in a `TextView`.
For example i want to drop **image of bread** under the **text of bread** in my `TextView`. I really want to show a drawable instead of background color for a part of text in a TextView. Is it possible with ImageSpan?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:drawablebottom="@drawable/bread"` in your textview

If you want it like a watermark, use ImageButton as follows, make sure you use a small icon-like image

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bread" />
```

Comment: ... drop an image under **a piece of text** ... . Not all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: image of bread under text of bread is something like watermark.

Comment: It seems that my question is not clear. I really want to show a drawable instead of background color for a part of text in a `TextView`. Is it possible with `ImageSpan`?

Comment: can you make an image in photoshop , so that we understand wat u exactly want

Answer (score 1):

you can just simply add [android:drawablebottom="@drawable/yourimage"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to the TextView in xml

or otherwise the equivalent in Java is

`public void  setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds  (Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)`

usage:

```
myText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,null, myNewDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code and try

In your XML File

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="Bread" android:id="@+id/mBtn1" />
```

In your Java File.

```
Button mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtn1);
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bread);
mBtn1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, d);
```

it will solve your problem.